# É necessário pagar alguma coisa para utilizar asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net

Eu ouvi que .NEt não é gratuito e que eu tenho que pagar para a Microsoft se eu publicar uma aplicação .net

É isso verdade?

Se eu quiser colocar instalar a tecnologia num servidor de páginas web terei de pagar alguma coisa ?

Comment: a principio, pagar o visual studio dependendo da situação, e certamente pagar a licençaa do windows onde vai estar rodando o IIS rsrs ah, se estiver usando SQL Server, acima da versão express tem que pagar tb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O framework .NET é gratuito, tanto a versão do ASP.NET e ASP.NET Core. O que pode ter feito a confusão é que antigamente o ambiente do .NET era todo em tecnologia Microsoft que é paga (Windows Server, possível Sql Server e possível Azure, etc.).

Com o surgimento do ASP.NET Core facilitou a não gastar. O novo framework tem suporte oficial da Microsoft para Linux e trabalha com um web server Kestrel, que é gratuito.

Quesito banco, é todo uma questão de técnico já que você não é obrigado a utilizar X banco de dados. Por ser ambos Microsoft, SQL Server e .NET, é comum ser a escolha. Porém, o mesmo é gratuito até 10GB (depende da versão), além disso é necessário pagar.

Comment: Só refrisando. Você não obrigado a utilizar o SQL Server, nem Oracle (banco de dados pagos) existem vários bancos de dados gratuitos muito bons no mercado.